# How to calculate hemisphericity?

Tags: geometry, volume

I need to calculate the hemisphericity of objects for a medical project. I'd like to find a way to calculate how close to a perfect hemisphere an object is. I've found a way to do this for sphericity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphericity)

Is there a similar way to calculate hemisphericity? I know the volume and the surface area (not including the base of the hemisphere) for these objects.

Thank you

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a similar calculation for hemisphericity (as far as I could find).  I'm concerned that as a 3-dimensional concept that only sphereicity is meaningful.  Depending on the application, it may make sense to double the volume and non-base surface area (as though you are placing two hemispheres next to each other) and then calculate the sphereicity.

Comment: The definition of sphericity is based on the fact that the sphere maximizes the volume surround by a surface of a given area. There are several ways one could come up with measurements of hemisphericity, but which would be best depends on what you know about your objects, and what use you plan to make of it. For instance if all objects are lying on a sheet that serves as the plane side of the hemisphere, and your goal is maximizing volume, then you can just take the ratio of volume to surface area not touching the plane.